# matplotlib plot filled with different layers by loop, colouring

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I produce multiple plots containing each 5 subplots, generated in a for loop.
How can I define the coloring of the subplots? Do I need something like a Matrix with numbers and colors and use it somehow like Matrix[z] instead of the Color?

```
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  for z in Var
    ax.plot(x, y, color='black', alpha=0.5 , label=labelString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you exactly mean. But if you mean plotting 5 different curves in the same plot, each in different color, this is one way you can do it. This allows you to choose colors as you want. In case you do not specify colors manually like in the code below, `python` will assign colors automatically. In that case you just have to write `ax.plot(x, y, label=r'y=%dx$^2$' %(i+1))`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'y']
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
for i in range(5):
    y = (i+1)*x**2
    ax.plot(x, y, color=colors[i], label=r'y=%dx$^2$' %(i+1))

plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```

**Output**

[image]